# Can you extend pack() to handle custom, variable length fields?

Tags: perl

The [Bitcoin protocol](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Variable_length_integer), in order to save space, encodes their integers using what they call variable length integers or varints.  The first byte of the varint encodes its length and its interpretation:

```
FirstByte  Value
< 0xfd     treat the byte itself as an 8 bit integer
0xfd       next 2 bytes form a 16 bit integer
0xfe       next 4 bytes form a 32 bit integer
0xff       next 8 bytes form a 64 bit integer
```

(All ints are little endian and unsigned).  I wrote the following function to unpack varints:

```
my $varint = "\xfd\x00\xff"; # \x00\xff in little endian == 65280 
say unpack_varint($varint);  # print 65280

sub unpack_varint{
    my $v = shift;
    my $first_byte = unpack "C", $v;
    say $first_byte;
    if ($first_byte < 253) { # \xfd == 253
        return $first_byte;
    }
    elsif ($first_byte == 253){
        return unpack "S<", substr $v, 1, 2;
    }
    elsif ($first_byte == 254){
        return unpack "L<", substr $v, 1, 4;
    }
    elsif ($first_byte == 255){
        return unpack "Q<", substr $v, 1, 8;
    }
    else{
        die "error";
    }
}
```

This works... but its very inelegant b/c if I have a long bytestring with embedded varints, I would have to read up to the beginning of the varint, pass the remainder to the function above, find out how long the encoded varint was, etc. etc.  Is there a better way to write this?  In particular, can I somehow extend `pack()` to support this kind of structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a set of `shift_$type` functions that read and delete some value at the beginning of the given string, so your code becomes something as the following:

```
my $buffer = ...;

my $val1 = shift_varint($buffer);
my $val2 = shift_string($buffer);
my $val3 = shift_uint32($buffer);
...
```

You can also add a multirecord "shifter":

```
my ($val1, $val2, $val3) = shift_multi($buffer, qw(varint string uint32));
```

If you need more speed you could also write a compiler which can convert a set of types into an unpacker sub.